# Passing a calling class into a subclass and calling a method from it when the subclass has completed a job

Tags: java, android

So, pretty much as the question describes. This is in the context of an Android app and I wanted to know if it's solid practice or a disgusting hack?

Basically class foo constructs class baz with 'this' as an argument, which baz then puts in a member variable. When baz has completed its task, it calls a public function in foo to return control and notify foo that baz has finished.

Does this make anyone here feel sick? Or is it accepted practice? If not, what's a better way to do things?

Thanks!

Comment: At the first glance it's too complicated. But it could be the only one way in your case. So using reflection of not depends on a particular task. You probably need to describe what do you want to do rather than to describe how you're doing in now.

Comment: Ideally I'd want the subclass to raise a flag or something, or run a method in the calling class when it's done. I've looked into event listeners and callbacks but I can't wrap my head around them, especially in the context of an app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perfectly normal.

In fact, if baz is a non-static class, declared inside foo, then it has that pointer to foo, implicitly (it is called "foo.this", in baz).

For instance:

```
findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) { handleClick(); }
        }
    );
```

That call to "handleClick()" up there is, implicitly a call to foo.this.handleClick() and exactly the kind of call you are discussing.

This is not to say that you aren't doing horrible things with the construct ;-).  As far as you describe it, though, it is absolutely normal.